# How do you convert a relational dataset with 3 columns to a 2d sparse matrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm using spark 2.0.0 with scala 2.11.

I have a dataframe that has 3 columns:

```
object_id  category_id   count
1          653           5
1          78            1
1          28            6
2          63            2
3          59            7
```

How do I convert it to this format?

```
1 653:5 78:1 28:6
2 63:2
3 59:7
```

Cheers

Comment: what did you try ? :)

Comment: @eliasah Looks like a - Why put effort ? Write question on stackoverflow. Let others solve my problem.

Comment: `yourDS.rdd.map(row => (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1), row.getInt(2))).groupBy({ (oid, cid, c) => iod }).map({ (oid, iter) => (oid, iter.foldLeft("")((acc, tup) => acc + tup._2 + ":" + tup._3)) })`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I've posted my answer below. This question is from when I was new to Spark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't want to leave this guy unanswered - turns out the `pivot` function after a `groupBy` does exactly what I want.

`dataset
  .groupBy("object_id")
  .pivot("category_id", listOfAllCategoryIds)`

Answer (score 1):

Using RDD's

```
yourDS.rdd
  .map(row => (row.getInt(0), row.getInt(1), row.getInt(2)))
  .grou‌​pBy({ (oid, cid, c) => iod })
  .map({ 
    (oid, iter) => (oid, iter.foldLeft("")((a‌​cc, tup) => acc + " " + tup._2 + ":" + tup._3))
  })
  .toDF("id", "hash")
```

Staying in DataSet world will be a bit difficult as you have to combine columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well my approach uses `DataFrame`s instead of `RDD`s, so it differs from the other answer.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StringType
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray


val a = sc.parallelize(Array(
  (1, 653, 5),
  (1, 78, 1),
  (1, 28, 6),
  (2, 63, 2),
  (3, 59, 7)
)).toDF("object_id", "category_id", "count")

val x = a.select(col("object_id"), concat(col("category_id"), lit(":") , col("count")).as("res"))

def concat_things(a: WrappedArray[String]) = a.reduce(_ + " " + _)

val conUDF = udf(concat_things _, StringType)

x.groupBy("object_id").agg(collect_list(col("res")).as("res")).select(col("object_id"), conUDF(col("res"))).show()

//+---------+---------------+
//|object_id|       UDF(res)|
//+---------+---------------+
//|        1|653:5 78:1 28:6|
//|        3|           59:7|
//|        2|           63:2|
//+---------+---------------+
```

You can check this answer on this [published notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2485090270202665/666001780394423/8589256059752547/latest.html)